# Associating an object with another object for GC clearup

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Is there any way of associating an object instance (object A) with a second object (object B) in a generalised way, so that when B gets collected A becomes eligable for collection? The same behaviour that would happen if B had an instance variable pointing to A, but without explicitly changing the class definition of B, and being able to do this in a dynamic way?

The same sort of effect could be done by using the Component.Disposed event in a funky way, but I don't want to make B disposable

**EDIT**

I'm basically creating a cache of objects that are associated with a single 'root' object, and I don't want the cache to be static, as there can be lots of root objects using different caches, so lots of memory will be used up when a root object is no longer used but the cached objects are still around.

So, I want a collection of cached objects to be associated with each 'root' object, without changing the root object definition. Sort of like metadata of an extra object reference attached to each root object instance. That way, each collection will get collected when the root object is collected, and not hang around like they would if a static cache was used.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there's a design flaw here. So if you have Cache A with object B in it, and object Z has reference to object B, you're saying when A goes away, you want B to go away too?  What is supposed to happen to object Z's reference to B?

Comment: There won't be references to cached objects outside of the root object. And if there was, I would want the normal CLR strong references to make sure it wasn't collected :)

Comment: If the A has the only reference to B, then B automatically becomes eligible for collection when A gets collected since there will no longer be any references to B.

Comment: I want to add this reference without explicitly having a variable in the class definition. Something like thread local storage, but done on an object instead of a thread.

Comment: So you're saying you don't want A to have a collection of the cached objects or B to have a Parent variable? What's the reason for this? I don't think this is possible because you'd have no reference to B so it would be cleaned up. You could create a 3rd object that linked A and B but now you've got more references. You'd also need a method that periodically cleaned up the reference, so that kills the automatic collecting.

Comment: A cache without an expiration policy is a memory leak.  The GC isn't going to help you with a policy beyond WeakReference, you'll have to make your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Probably not.  Can you explain more of what you're trying to do?  There's a chance WeakReference might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RelatedReference<A, B>
{
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public B Referent
    {
        get {return b;}
    }

    public RelatedReference(A a, B b)
    {
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Then just use RelatedReference every where you would use B like so:

```
    var Bref = new RelatedReference<A, B>(new A(), new B());
    Bref.Referent.Foo();
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this helps?

Comment: If another object has a reference to B, B still won't be collected.

Comment: Yes, you have to be careful not to set any other references to B. I also agree that the WeakReference class might be the way to go.

Comment: @thecoop - You're essentially accessing everything through a generic wrapper object. Once the wrapper object is collected, all of its references are collected. You do have to be careful not to assign the Referent property to any other variables though so this solution is a bit brittle... but it will work in general.